# VBA Show / Hide Images or Shapes on Command Button Click Event To Sort Data

Tags: excel, vba, click, show-hide, shapes

I am developing a program that has multiple columns of Data that can be sorted by several of the columns. For aesthetics I am using Command Buttons click event to toggle sorting in ascending or descending order. My code is pretty simple. I am using images of "up" arrows and "down" arrows as ascending / descending indicators. All of the images are on the worksheet and depending on the sort method, the click event shows or hides the appropriate image.The coding is working correctly with one issue that I wasnt thinking about. When a user clicks the button to sort, that arrow shows and hides correctly for that column however the other columns still show an arrow which can confuse the user. I would like to hide the other images / arrows except for the images / arrows in the column that is being sorted.

See Attached Image For Clarification
[image: Example]

In the photo above if the Player ID Command Button is pressed again the up arrow will hide and a down arrow will be visible but the other arrows will stay exactly as they are. I would like only the column being sorted to show the arrows.

The code below is used in the worksheet module using the command button click event.

```
Private Sub cmbAgentID_Click()

    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picAgentIDUp")).Visible = False Then
        Call SortByAgentAsc 'sort ascending
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picAgentIDUp")).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picAgentIDDown")).Visible = False
    Else
        Call SortByAgentDes 'sort descending
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picAgentIDDown")).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picAgentIDUp")).Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub cmbAllHands_Click()
    
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picAllHandsUp")).Visible = False Then
        Call SortByHandsAsc 'sort ascending
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picAllHandsUp")).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picAllHandsDown")).Visible = False
    Else
        Call SortByHandsDes 'sort descending
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picAllHandsDown")).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picAllHandsUp")).Visible = False
    End If
        
End Sub
Private Sub cmbCashHands_Click()

    
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picCashUp")).Visible = False Then
        Call SortByCashAsc 'sort ascending
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picCashUp")).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picCashDown")).Visible = False
    Else
        Call SortByCashDes 'sort descending
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picCashDown")).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picCashUp")).Visible = False
    End If
        
End Sub
Private Sub cmbEmbers_Click()
    
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picEmbersUp")).Visible = False Then
        Call SortByEmbersAsc 'sort ascending
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picEmbersUp")).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picEmbersDown")).Visible = False
    Else
        Call SortByEmbersDes 'sort descending
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picEmbersDown")).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picEmbersUp")).Visible = False
    End If
    
End Sub
Private Sub cmbFees_Click()
            
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picFeeUp")).Visible = False Then
        Call SortByFeeAsc 'sort ascending
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picFeeUp")).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picFeeDown")).Visible = False
    Else
        Call SortByFeeDes 'sort descending
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picFeeDown")).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("picFeeUp")).Visible = False
    End If
        
End Sub
```

Any Suggestions? I have been looking at ShapeRange which is new to me and Shape Arrays, but havent found what I am looking for yet.

-------**Updated Code Below with Suggested Improvements Not Working**-------

Created "Rotate It" Sub and assigned macro to a single arrow.

```
Sub RotateIt()
  
Dim s As Shape: Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    
    If s.Rotation = 0 Then
        s.Rotation = 180
    Else
        s.Rotation = 0
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Created 1 sub for Sorting and I think my problem is here...

```
Sub SortByEverything(sortKey As Range, Optional boolAsc As Boolean)
  
  Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
  Dim rng As Range: Set rng = sh.Range("B3:M" & lastrow)
  
    If boolAsc Then
        With rng 'your existing code for ACENDING sorting type, but using supplied sortKey...
            .Sort Key1:=sortKey, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        End With
        Debug.Print "Sort Ascending..."
    Else
        With rng 'your existing code for ACENDING sorting type, but using supplied sortKey...
            .Sort Key1:=sortKey, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        End With
        Debug.Print "Sort Descending..."
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Created Class Module ButtonName

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cmdButton As MSForms.CommandButton
```

---

```
Public Sub cmdButton_Click()

Dim sArr As Shape: Set sArr = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Arrow")

sArr.Top = cmdButton.Top: sArr.Left = cmdButton.Left + cmdButton.Width
    If sArr.Rotation = 0 Then
        SortByEverything cmdButton.TopLeftCell, True
        sArr.Rotation = 180
    Else
        SortByEverything cmdButton.TopLeftCell
        sArr.Rotation = 0
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Created the worksheet activate sub

```
Option Explicit

Private arrEvents As Collection
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim ActXButEvents As ButtonName, shp As Shape
Set arrEvents = New Collection
varSplitCol = 0
varSplitRow = 4
    
    Call EnhancePerformance
    Call FreezeSheetPanes
    
    For Each shp In Me.Shapes
       If shp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
           If TypeOf shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
               Set ActXButEvents = New ButtonName
               Set ActXButEvents.cmdButton = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object
               arrEvents.Add ActXButEvents
           End If
       End If
    Next
    
    Call NormalPerformance
End Sub
```

Comment: Whenever you enter the If and the Else, call a sub that hides all arrows. Then you only have to care about showing the single one that should be visible.

Comment: I did that using the code below but my if statement acts as a toggle for my command button so my problem now is alternating  my arrows. If the down arrow is selected than my click event is going to call for the ascending order macro and it will hide the down arrow and show the up arrow. if the button is clicked again the if statement will see the up arrow is present so it will call the descending macro and  it will hide the up arrow and show the down arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next approach, please. Create a `Sub` to be called by all buttons `Click` event:

```
Sub HideArrows(sh As Worksheet)
 Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In sh.Shapes
        If Right(s.Name, 2) = "Up" Or _
            Right(s.Name, 4) = "Down" Then s.Visible = msoFalse
    Next
End Sub
```

Then use your existing code in this way:

```
Private Sub cmbAgentID_Click() 'proceed in a similar way to all the other click events
  Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
  
    HideArrows sh
    If sh.Shapes.Range(Array("picAgentIDUp")).Visible = False Then
        Call SortByAgentAsc 'sort ascending
        sh.Shapes.Range(Array("picAgentIDUp")).Visible = True
    Else
        Call SortByAgentDes 'sort descending
        sh.Shapes.Range(Array("picAgentIDDown")).Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Edited: Try the next different approach, please. It is very compact. **The whole necessary code** will be the next one, in a standard module:

1. Create a single (Up) arrow shape and name it "Arrow"
2. Each (Form type) button will target the same `Sub`, so assign to all of them the next code. For an ActiveX button I will show the approach (a little more complicated, but not too much) at the end:

```
    Sub Button_Click()
        Dim s As Shape: Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
        Dim sArr As Shape: Set sArr = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Arrow")
        
        sArr.Rop = s.top: sArr.left = s.left + s.width
        If sArr.Rotation = 0 Then
            SortByEverything s.TopLeftCell, True 'ascending
            sArr.Rotation = 180
        Else
            SortByEverything s.TopLeftCell       'descending
            sArr.Rotation = 0
        End If
    End Sub
```

3. Use the sorting `Subs` built in the next way. They will receive the sorting key according to each pressed button position:

```
    Sub SortByEverything(sortKey As Range, Optional boolAsc As Boolean)
      Dim sh As Worksheet
      Set sh = ActiveSheet
      
      If boolAsc Then
        'your existing code for ACENDING sorting type, but using supplied sortKey...
        '....
        Debug.Print "Sort Ascending..."
      Else
        'your existing code for ACENDING sorting type, but using supplied sortKey...
        '....
        Debug.Print "Sort Descending..."
      End If
    End Sub
```

4. In order to change the arrow orientation/sorting type, please assign the next code to the "Arrow" shape:

```
    Sub RotateIt()
      Dim s As Shape: Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
        If s.Rotation = 0 Then
            s.Rotation = 180
        Else
            s.Rotation = 0
        End If
    End Sub
```

This approach philosophy would be the next: When press a button the "Arrow" shape will be moved to its right side. According to its `rotation` property, the sorting will be done ascending or descending. Then the arrow rotation will be adapted. If it remains down oriented and next time, for a different column, you need to sort descending, just click the arrow shape and it will rotate for the appropriate sorting type. You need only a single sorting `Sub` being `informed` about the sorting key and sorting type...

5. In case of ActiveX button, `Application.Coller` does not return the shape calling the sub name and a Class Events Wrapper is necessary...

a) Insert a class module, name it `ButtonName` and copy the next code:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cmdButton As MSForms.CommandButton

Public Sub cmdButton_Click()
    Dim sArr As Shape: Set sArr = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Arrow")
    
    sArr.top = cmdButton.top: sArr.left = cmdButton.left + cmdButton.width
    If sArr.Rotation = 0 Then
        SortByEverything cmdButton.TopLeftCell, True
        sArr.Rotation = 180
    Else
        SortByEverything cmdButton.TopLeftCell
        sArr.Rotation = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: **No click events for all ActiveX buttons** are necessary (for this specific task)!

b) Create a Private variable at **the sheet level** module. On top of it, in the declarations area:

```
     Public arrEvents As Collection
```

c) Use `Worksheet_Activate` event (of course in the sheet keeping the buttons), in order to initialize the class for all ActiveX type buttons:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Dim ActXButEvents As ButtonName, shp As Shape

 Set arrEvents = New Collection

 For Each shp In Me.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
        If TypeOf shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
            Set ActXButEvents = New ButtonName
            Set ActXButEvents.cmdButton = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object
            arrEvents.aDD ActXButEvents
        End If
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Note: When you have the code, it is not possible to press a button on the working sheet, without triggering the sheet Activate event. But, during your code preparation, **it is necessary to activate another sheet and then reactivate it**. Just in order to trigger the before mentioned event.

Check it please, if interested, and send some feedback.

Comment: This is almost working. Very close! When I click the command button it hides the other buttons and sorts 1 time just ascending. I think the problem is that since my up arrow is layered on top of the down arrow, when I press the command button again to toggle the descending arrow it stays hidden. My if statement says "if the down arrow if visable then sort ascending and hide the down image and show the up image". if the first step is to hide all of the images then the if statement wont get my desired result after the first sort. Is there a better way to write the if statement in your opinion?

Comment: I really like the thought behind your code. I am doing something wrong because I cant get it to work. First sub you mention is Button_Click and I left that sub out because I have Activexcontrols. Was I supposed to leave that sub in? So at this point my sort buttons press but dont provide sort and dont change the arrow configuration. Is my sort code correct?

Comment: `If boolAsc Then
            With rng 'your existing code for ACENDING sorting type, but using supplied sortKey...
                .Sort Key1:=sortKey, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
            End With
            Debug.Print "Sort Ascending..."
        Else
            With rng 'your existing code for ACENDING sorting type, but using supplied sortKey...
                .Sort Key1:=sortKey, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
            End With
            Debug.Print "Sort Descending..."
        End If`

Comment: im sorry but i tried to format that code within the comment and i have messed that up as well but hopefully you can see it FaneDuru.

Comment: @Adam Rhodes: I cannot understand anything from your code... 1. `Button_Click` is useless for ActiveX buttons. 2. Did you insert a class module, named it `ButtonName` and pasted my code in it? 3. Did you copied `Worksheet_Activate` event code in the sheet module where you have the buttons in discussion? 4. After doing that, did you activate another sheet and reactivate the one with the event in its module?

Comment: yes I created the class module, pasted the code and I also activated another sheet and reactivated the primary. Would it be alright to email you my code? I would post it here but I don't know how to post new code within the comments.

Comment: @Adam Rhodes: No need to post the code within the comments. Edit your question and post, at the end, the code you want showing us...

Comment: I edited my original post with your code. Im sure I messed up the sort but let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I notice that I didn't include my descending order for the sort and that I have ascending order at both ends of the if statement. I can fix that easy enough but that isnt the issue. the sort isn't working anyway. I just wanted to point that out in case others catch that.

Comment: Now I am driving. I can look at it after some hours...

Comment: Forget now about sorting! Does the code move the arrow and display "Sort...." in Immediate window? Did you test the code as it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217324/discussion-between-adam-rhodes-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Thank you to FaneDuru for helping me. I used the coding that FaneDuru provided but I separated the Up arrows and down Arrows to still leave the majority of them grouped but had to individually hide the other ones. For example in the Player ID column. In order for me to toggle the up and down arrows I had to at least have 2 arrows available. In FaneDuru code it only left me with 1 arrow to work with since the rest were not visible. The only way i could figure to to it was:

- if down arrow was visible before the click event then I could hide all down arrows and all up arrows except for the arrow in that column. When the click event happens the up arrow becomes visible and the down arrow is hidden.
- It was more work because i had to put the other shapes in an array individually

This is now fixed but there is always room to improve it.
Code for worksheet module

```
Private Sub cmbAgentID_Click()
    
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
            
    If sh.Shapes.Range(Array("picAgentIDUp")).Visible = msoFalse Then
        hidedownarrows sh
        Call SortByAgentAsc 'sort ascending
        With sh.Shapes
            .Range(Array("picAgentIDUp")).Visible = msoTrue
            .Range(Array("picCashUp", "picAllHandsUp", "picEmbersUp", "picRBAmtUp", "PicRBUp", "picFeeUp", "picIDUp")).Visible = msoFalse
        End With
    Else
        HideupArrows sh
        Call SortByAgentDes 'sort descending
        With sh.Shapes
            .Range(Array("picAgentIDDown")).Visible = msoTrue
            .Range(Array("picCashdown", "picAllHandsdown", "picEmbersdown", "picRBAmtdown", "PicRBdown", "picFeedown", "picIDdown")).Visible = msoFalse
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
Private Sub cmbAllHands_Click()
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
    
    If sh.Shapes.Range(Array("picAllHandsUp")).Visible = msoFalse Then
        hidedownarrows sh
        Call SortByHandsAsc 'sort ascending
        With sh.Shapes
            .Range(Array("picAllHandsUp")).Visible = msoTrue
            .Range(Array("picCashUp", "picAgentIDUp", "picEmbersUp", "picRBAmtUp", "PicRBUp", "picFeeUp", "picIDUp")).Visible = msoFalse
        End With
    Else
        HideupArrows sh
        Call SortByHandsDes 'sort descending
        With sh.Shapes
            .Range(Array("picAllHandsDown")).Visible = msoTrue
            .Range(Array("picCashdown", "picAgentIDdown", "picEmbersdown", "picRBAmtdown", "PicRBdown", "picFeedown", "picIDdown")).Visible = msoFalse
        End With
    End If
                
End Sub
Private Sub cmbCashHands_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
    
    If sh.Shapes.Range(Array("picCashUp")).Visible = msoFalse Then
        hidedownarrows sh
        Call SortByCashAsc 'sort ascending
        With sh.Shapes
            .Range(Array("picCashUp")).Visible = msoTrue
            .Range(Array("picAllHandsUp", "picAgentIDUp", "picEmbersUp", "picRBAmtUp", "PicRBUp", "picFeeUp", "picIDUp")).Visible = msoFalse
        End With
    Else
        HideupArrows sh
        Call SortByCashDes 'sort descending
        With sh.Shapes
            .Range(Array("picCashDown")).Visible = msoTrue
            .Range(Array("picAllHandsDown", "picAgentIDdown", "picEmbersdown", "picRBAmtdown", "PicRBdown", "picFeedown", "picIDdown")).Visible = msoFalse
        End With
        End If
    
End Sub
Private Sub cmbEmbers_Click()
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
    
    If sh.Shapes.Range(Array("picEmbersUp")).Visible = msoFalse Then
        hidedownarrows sh
        Call SortByEmbersAsc 'sort ascending
        With sh.Shapes
            .Range(Array("picEmbersUp")).Visible = msoTrue
            .Range(Array("picAllHandsUp", "picAgentIDUp", "picCashUp", "picRBAmtUp", "PicRBUp", "picFeeUp", "picIDUp")).Visible = msoFalse
        End With
    Else
        HideupArrows sh
        Call SortByEmbersDes 'sort descending
        With sh.Shapes
            .Range(Array("picEmbersDown")).Visible = msoTrue
            .Range(Array("picAllHandsDown", "picAgentIDdown", "picCashDown", "picRBAmtdown", "PicRBdown", "picFeedown", "picIDdown")).Visible = msoFalse
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
Private Sub cmbFees_Click()
            
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet

    If sh.Shapes.Range(Array("picFeeUp")).Visible = msoFalse Then
        hidedownarrows sh
        Call SortByFeeAsc 'sort ascending
        With sh.Shapes
            .Range(Array("picFeeUp")).Visible = msoTrue
            .Range(Array("picAllHandsUp", "picAgentIDUp", "picCashUp", "picRBAmtUp", "PicRBUp", "picEmbersUp", "picIDUp")).Visible = msoFalse
        End With
    Else
        HideupArrows sh
        Call SortByFeeDes 'sort descending
        With sh.Shapes
            .Range(Array("picFeeDown")).Visible = msoTrue
            .Range(Array("picAllHandsDown", "picAgentIDdown", "picCashDown", "picRBAmtdown", "PicRBdown", "picEmbersDown", "picIDdown")).Visible = msoFalse
        End With
    End If
        
End Sub
```

Code for Standard Module

```
Sub HideupArrows(sh As Worksheet)

Dim s As Shape

   For Each s In sh.Shapes
       If Right(s.Name, 2) = "Up" Then
           s.Visible = msoFalse
       End If
   Next

End Sub
Sub hidedownarrows(sh As Worksheet)

Dim s As Shape

    For Each s In sh.Shapes
        If Right(s.Name, 4) = "Down" Then
            s.Visible = msoFalse
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice... Voted it up.  Are your buttons Form or ActiveX type? I can propose you a much compact variant, involving a single arrow which to be moved to the right side of the pressed button and flipped according to the previous sorting way... You can also change between 'Ascending/Descending` clicking on the arrow... For Form buttons the code will be simpler, due to the Application.Caller meaning. All buttons will target the same Click sub. If you will like to show you such a way, I can do it... In fact, I will adapt my answer and post it like variant. I think you will love it...

Comment: I apologize for the delay. I am really excited to try out this new code. I am going to try it out tonight and I will get back to you. I am only using Activex buttons because i can blend the buttons in with the Cell Headers using background color and I cannot do that with form controls that I am aware of. Would I be able to use you code with Shapes. I could make shape buttons with the same results possibly.

Comment: My code provides a solution for ActiveX buttons, too. The code works also with shapes. You only must follow the procedure used for `Form` shapes. I mean, you must assign the same `Button_Click` `Sub` to them. Without any changes. `Application.Caller` returns the shape name and the shape object is obtained exactly in the same way like in the `Form` buttons...